# PHP Copy randomly creating 0 byte file

Tags: php, copy, fopen

I am having some strange behavior and I cannot find a reason for it.

I have a page for members that when accessed for the very first time, a file of variables is created for them. The file is named "memberUserName.php" and stored outside of root.

The file creation works well and it does exactly what it is supposed to. However, recently I have had about 30% of new members creating their accounts, logging in and visiting the page and their created file is 0 bytes. The member right before them.. perfect execution. The member after them, perfect execution. 4th and 5th members.. 0 byte files.

I have checked everything I can think of. It happens to all OSes, on all browsers and so far in at least 17 different countries. Meanwhile, those same browsers, OSes and country locations also have successful file creations.

If I manually delete the 0 byte file and have the member go back to the page, about 50-60% of the time, the file is created successfully, the rest of the time, another 0-byte file.

The code I am using is this:

```
    if (!file_exists('/path/to/Files/' . $context['user']['name'] . '.php')){
$myfile= fopen('/path/to/Files/Storage/' . $context['user']['name'] . '.php',"w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
copy ('path/to/file-to-copy/file.php', '/path/to/Files/Storage/' . $context['user']['name'] . '.php');
```

Anyone have any ideas what can cause this? I am running out of things to try.

Comment: You don't need to create the file with `fopen()` in order to copy it. BTW, I guess `fopen()` creates and locks the file, so copy could fail.

Comment: @Triby This may be true, but the way I understand it is that copy will look for the file, if it doesn't exist, it creates it. If it does exist, it overwrites it. Since the variable values in the created file will change, that file cannot be overwritten. So fopen checks for the file, if it doesn't exist, creates and opens it, then copy does its thing. If it does exist, copy isn't run.

Comment: You've already checked that file doesn't exist... that's what `file_exists()` do.

Comment: ...but because of the 
[race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), between the lines another user could theoretically create a file with the same name.

Comment: so if I remove the entire fopen() line, I will get the same result without the file being overwritten?

@draz I don't think that is a worry as the username is set by the forum and stored in the database, which already requires a unique display name to be used before the account can even be created. Without a display name, they cannot log in to the page to have the memberfile created in the first place.

Comment: the zero-byte file is created by `fopen`. so finally only the `copy` failed, as mentioned, one would expect to do so because of the `fopen`. actually, `copy` should _always_ fail after fopen because of the locking

Comment: @draz thanks, I have made the change Triby mentioned and am awaiting those members with the 0 byte files to log in for the day. I will keep an eye out and see if anything changes.

Comment: I'm my experience, failed file system operations usually trigger a warning with a more or less accurate error description. Please double-check that your system is configured to let warnings through and log or display them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález all error logs and reporting systems, both on server and on site are open and operational and there is no report of this at all. That was the first thing I checked (and the 3rd, 4th,...) 

It is still happening, even without the fopen() line. Still random. Still no common theme as to who it affects. I'm lost.

Comment: @JTPledger did u find something?